# Import shortcut in IDEA Scratch files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, scratch-file

I really like the possibility to write Java Scratch files with IntelliJ, what I don't understand, is why the auto import feature does not work? On a project's .java file, if I want to use something that is not imported, I write it's name, like `Matcher`, press `Alt+Enter`, and a class import menu pops up and selecting on of the imports automatically generates the import row for me. Why does that not work in Scratch files (If I press `alt+Enter` there, nothing happens, I have to manually type in all the imports)?

Edit.: I use IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3 
Build #IU-163.11103.6,
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86
JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is missing and there is an issue about that logged in YouTrack:

- [IDEABKL-7439](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7439) Scratches: "Import class" intention/quick-fix is not available

Comment: Oh, I though I messed up some settings for the Scratches, Thanks, I hope it gets fixed.